# Making the subscript under the summation

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

I'm writing some formulas inside a `tabular`. My formulas have summation but the subscript is showing next to the summation not under it! How can I make it under it?

Example (j is next to summation!):

[image]

Comment: `\displaystyle`

Answer (score 68):

You can force the subscripts to be under the summation, by using `\limits`, like this:

```
\sum\limits_{j=1} A_{xj}
```

An alternative way is to change the typesetting style of the formula by using `\displaystyle`. You probably already noticed, that the typesetting of math differs depending on what 'mode' your in: `inline math` or `display math`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
This sum $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i}  $ looks different than
\[
    \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i}
\]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I think there should be a `\limits_` in the sum in the third from last line in your code.

Comment: @cgnorthcutt It is not needed, since display style automatically switches to this style of limits. The MWE was specifically intended to show this difference.